# Parse.com Tried to save an object with a new, unsaved child with findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock in Swift

Tags: swift, parse-platform, where-clause

Here are the definitions of entities:

```
class Event : PFObject, PFSubclassing {
    override class func load() {
        superclass()?.load()
        self.registerSubclass()
    }

    class func parseClassName() -> String! {
        return "Event"
    }
}
```

˚
Now I am trying to retrieve list of teams belongs to Event:

```
    var teams: [Team] = []
    var query = PFQuery(className: "Team")
    query.includeKey("event")
    if (event != nil) {
        query.whereKey("event", equalTo: event)
    }
    query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [AnyObject]!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
```

I am getting error as,

[Error]: Caught "NSInternalInconsistencyException" with reason "Tried to save an object with a new, unsaved child.":

But if I remove the whereKey statement: query.whereKey("event", equalTo: event), the error disappears.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's been a couple months, so I hope you've solved your problem by now, but are you by chance using anonymous users? Sometimes you get this error when you're have a new anonymous user that hasn't been saved to the cloud yet. The problem can be solved to checking to see if the current user has an objectId, and if they don't, saving a dummy object.

Comment: Did you create the Event object just before trying to use it? I'm seeing something similar when trying to initialize a new subclass of PFObject in Swift.